# Generalizing the Stone-von-Neumann theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, mathematics

The [Stone-von-Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) states (in rough terms) that a pair of operators $\left(\hat{Q}, \hat{P}\right)$ satisfying the exponentiated canonical commutation relation $e^{is\hat{Q}}e^{it\hat{P}} = e^{-ist}e^{it\hat{P}}e^{is\hat{Q}}$ acting irreducibly are unitarily equivalent to the standard position and momentum operators $\hat{q}, \hat{p}$ acting on $L^2(\mathbf{R})$.

I would like to figure how to extend this result. Precisely, given 2 operators $\hat{A}, \hat{B}$ satisfying the commutation relations $\left[\hat{B}, \hat{A}\right] = if(\hat{A})$ (for some Borel function $f$) acting irreducibly, can one say anything about how $\left(\hat{A}, \hat{B}\right)$ relates to $\left(\hat{q}, \frac{1}{2}\left(f(\hat{q})\hat{p} + \hat{p}f(\hat{q})\right)\right)$ (which indeed satisfy the latter commutation relation)?

Loosely speaking, the Stone-von-Neumann theorem corresponds to $f = 1$ (this is not rigorously true as it only applies to operators satisfying the *exponentiated* canonical commutation relation, which is stronger than the basic one). To start (hopefully) simple, I would now like to look at $f(x) = x$. I have tried to see whether the proof of the Stone-von-Neumann may be adapted there, following the derivation given in Hall, *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians*, paragraph 14.3, but this does not seem promising. I anticipate though that this case may still be simple enough as the relation $\left[\hat{A}, \hat{B}\right] = i\hat{A}$ gives you a nice $2$-dimensional Lie algebra structure; this would no longer be the case for general $f$, e.g $f(x) = x^2$.

Any idea how to tackle the problem?

P.S.: Also, do not hesitate to tell if you think the question would the better  suited for Math StackExchange.

EDIT: [This paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123612X00120/1-s2.0-S0022123612001863/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEF4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIBOfE1iwlucHxorF3SwcW8H45ULHggjYTpoGa8n4jIcFAiBThuMPdkod4DK04Zi2wanwL35zzByoqmJpxNyAlgelgCrZAgin%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAIaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMGSfEOqRFkZB%2FbpufKq0CEzQa4PRoydbHbgnpsFqIwkx4nZzI7pEBk%2B2IdOBy7Jd76kdnzSgCQXuxh%2Bg7BroARiZWW2ba9HHmKhQQP9Wl9yOvl%2BwMThosEVYGCw4mAIdjaNbUt8fmJwL%2B3SAPTt7Ux%2BH0%2FhySIlxK%2BtvEWYZepF1i29b69zF7c0bKThtpqNuAV3Yey%2BZnYT9Bu4nWzNqiIUW6Q2Tulpg0jSXV6xuVqmXhS%2B49PYbTefXLIR3XM0byRTbtKeVBCmi%2FyL4adxaCSbgXhElhu6sqhjdkqcr9C2igavE15%2Bc6cJuRsOKvK7Bit7opzIdiuTUyvHyJkJ8nDkS6XIXEESnf0m2%2Fkf4uvY0L9BJksIXiN7Snb6%2Bw0%2FAzXb28OTYu1CiiQWg10YQ7kL4%2F5S0%2BEjvh8Z0eYDCU%2FLPvBTrQAppIvFEXqvSxK7ra2iLKGsiK6wAqVcM1TsUsuIWKb5%2FNCdN2dIkRHCw0ePtX9l%2BGtqQ0BSMpSkr%2BnH6FsS8YqMQJyOLaLVB3xncbXpH8fYchvi642U6cmJj31%2F%2Fn6XC8pxbxKgCwQTz2ICs0FBxBI56D640Cs6iFzjZdgnfT4t5rGXyP0EyWUkxuiPII0RHSq9vHq3HPlJjmWjbqzojEDgzlcl06nJOpQjIkVOYrdTphMOCfxtckRqkydCv2n5jcBSLqp0bRtsG4S%2FA2HiuMslh4BHYT9CgYRHaZD3%2BCYtvfkJli8pRTDwLVHY%2BofQNyDviv%2FkuTBGs3Ad68eXaCTwJcQP2LxFitoK9cJubRD8ToIRBYne9h%2FPf95bQ%2FJSMdHK0gCvUEU0h8wlMCf1vW190Szmw0JdzOWP9rwwNqbWq14XduIdS7KxRoGBnPi%2B%2FxHg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20191208T144928Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY6WBLTW6J%2F20191208%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=8092b4a00d7b48e4f1da04d6b9bff687ba806e253b9a507c2a8675baaac4bc7c&hash=1f092455ea6f55ad674a1a276906a430caf745eea143105549f02b3614c3bd27&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022123612001863&tid=spdf-fa0acc74-6d64-4bcd-8d74-02608d9ff759&sid=51a150589618844b617bead9ac009c0dbd6bgxrqb&type=client) may be relevant to the discussion in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure why you assume that two arbitrary operators relate to $q$ and $p$ at all. If the operators in question do not have fully continuous spectrum, then certainly neither of them can be mapped to $q$, dooming your ansatz from the start (this is also part of the reason SvN needs the exponentiated relation). Worse, your 2d Lie algebra example does not have any infinite-dimensional irreducible unitary representations, hence there cannot be a SvN analogue for it. It seems to me that you need much stronger hypotheses here to say anything.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Concerning the "2d Lie algebra" example you mentioned, do you mean the one involving $\hat{q}$ and $\frac{1}{2}\left(\hat{q}\hat{p} + \hat{p}\hat{q}\right)$? (In this case, $e^{it\hat{B}} = e^{\frac{it}{2}\left(\hat{q}\hat{p} + \hat{p}\hat{q}\right)}$ is a squeeze operator in the position space). Can you expand (maybe pointing to some references) on why in this case there exists no infinite-dimensional irreducible unitary representation?

Comment: I meant your algebra $[A,B] = \mathrm{i}A$ - there is only one 2d non-Abelian Lie algebra, the affine algebra in 1 dimension. All irreps of this algebra are one-dimensional, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791386/143136. I.e. your starting point "Two operators $A,B$ acting irreducibly with $[A,B] = \mathrm{i}f(A)$" is inconsistent for the choice $f(A) = A$ (in fact, it is inconsistent for every function of $A$ whose result is a linear combination of $A$ and $B$, because that's always the same two-dimensional algebra, just with different basis).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am still confused though (sorry, my background in representation theory is a bit weak) how this applies to the operators $e^{it\hat{q}}, e^{it\left(\hat{q}\hat{p} + \hat{p}\hat{q}\right)}$ acting on $L^2(R)$. Is it that $L^2(R)$ cannot be decomposed in irreps in this case?

Comment: The only generalization of the SvN theorem I know of is the SNAG theorem.

Comment: No, I'm saying that 1. Any irreducible action of $[A,B] = \mathrm{i}A$ is on a one-dimensional space. 2. It therefore cannot be unitarily equivalent to *any* pair of operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, since that space is not one-dimensional but unitary equivalences preserve cardinality.

Comment: @ACuriousMind But do you agree that $A = \hat{q}, B = \frac{1}{2}(\hat{q}\hat{p} + \hat{p}\hat{q})$ do satisfy $[B, A] = iA$ and that their exponentiated version acts on $L^2(R)$? In this case, I agree based on the result you mentionned that this action on $L^2(\mathbf{R})$ cannot be irreducible (in fact, one can easily see that the functions with support in $\mathbf{R} _+$ or $\mathbf{R} _-$ give 2 obvious stable subspaces). My question is now whether you can decompose $L^2(\mathbf{R})$ in irreps.

Answer (score 2):

The only theorem that could be useful, I think,  is a theorem by Nelson proving what follows. Suppose we have a base for a representation of a certain Lie algebra in terms of $n$ densely defined (anti)-symmetric operators $A_j$  on a common  dense domain $D$ in a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose also that  $\sum_j A_j^2$ is essentially selfadjoint, then the operators $A_j$ are the generators of a unitary strongly-continuous rep of the simply connected Lie group $G$ whose Lie algebra is $g$.

Now, if the representation $U$ is irreducible and you know the classes of irreducible equivalent unitary representations of $G$, then $U$ must be unitarily equivalent to one of them. For the Weyl-Heisenberg group there is only one such representation, but this case is very peculiar. For instance you know that for $SU(2)$ there is an infinite number of those representations.

Regarding the case $[B,A] =iA$ that is the Lie algebra of the triangular subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. If $A^2+B^2$ is essentially selfadjoint and the rep is irreducible, your rep must be unitarily equivalent to one if that group (which are many).